# Transversal vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, transversality

Let $X$ be a vector field on some manifold $M$, $Y \subset M$ a submanifold.

What does it mean for $X$ to be transversal to $Y$ , denoted  $Y \pitchfork X$?

It appears in my lecture in the following definition:

$(M, \omega)$ symplectic. A hypersurface $W \subset M$ is called of contact type, if there exists a vector field $Y$ defined on a neighborhood of $W$ in $M$, s.t.

1)$Y \pitchfork W$

2)$L_Y \omega = \omega$

Comment: First, you would always put the $Y$ after the "transverse" symbol. Second, one ordinarily talks about a smooth mapping $f\colon N\to M$ being transverse to a submanifold $Y\subset M$. Where did you find this exact phrasing? Quote more of the source, please.

Comment: The source is my lecture, it is in the definition for hypersurface of contact type.

Comment: Most likely, this means that for each $w\in W$, $Y_w\notin T_wW$.

Comment: I concur with @MoisheKohan's comment. (Nevertheless, this is not standard parlance.) Note that the notations in your first post and in the portion you added are inconsistent with one another.